# Powershell filter one attribute against another

Tags: powershell, active-directory, filtering

I am trying to find a way to say `Get-AdUser -Filter {CN -ne DisplayName}` but I get an error since it is expecting a string instead of an attribute.

I know I can do `Get-ADUser -Filter * | ?{}` but that is done on the client side and is unusable when thousands of records are involved.

Any idea how I can compare `CN` to `Displayname` in the `-Filter` or `-LDAPFilter`?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The LDAP specification does not allow for searching based on the comparison of two attributes.  The specification allows for comparison of attributes to values.  Within Powershell you can easily run this comparison in the pipeline with a `where-object` command.  It will require you to look at each object.